# Error in shell script

Tags: qt, shell, install-name-tool

I'm using a shell script to help me resolve library paths so I can send out my app bundle.  I don't know much about shell scripts and was hacking something together from other pieces so I really don't know how to resolve the issue.  The issue revolves around lines like `done << ...`

Here's some code!  Note, this is based off of a Qt project.

```
echo "Below is the list of install_name_tools that need to be added:"
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    baseName=`basename "$file"`
    #echo "otool -L \"$file\" | grep -e \"*$baseName\""
    hasUsrLocal=`otool -L "$file" | grep -v -e "*$baseName" | grep -v libgcc_s.1.dylib | grep -v libstdc++.6.dylib | grep "/usr/local\|/Users"`
    if [ -n "$hasUsrLocal" ]; then
        #echo "WARNING: $file has /usr/local dependencies"
        #echo "\"$hasUsrLocal\""

        #echo "To Fix:"

        while read line; do
            #Remove extra info
            library=`echo "$line" | perl -pe 's/(.*?)\s\(compatibility version.*/\1/'`
            libraryBaseName=`basename "$library"`
            frameworkNameBase="$libraryBaseName.framework"
            isframework=`echo "$library" | grep "$frameworkNameBase"`

            unset fixCommand;
            if [ -n "$isframework" ]; then
                #Print out how to fix the framework
                frameworkName=`echo $library | perl -pe "s/.*?($frameworkNameBase\/.+)/\1/"`
                fixCommand=`echo "install_name_tool -change \"$library\" \"@executable_path/../Frameworks/$frameworkName\" \"$file\""`
            else
                #Print out how to fix the regular dylib
                if [ "$baseName" != "$libraryBaseName" ]; then
                    fixCommand=`echo "install_name_tool -change \"$library\" \"@executable_path/../Frameworks/$libraryBaseName\" \"$file\""`
                fi
            fi

            echo "$fixCommand"
        done << (echo "$hasUsrLocal")
        #echo "---------------------------------------------------------"
    fi

done << (find MyProgram.app -type f -print0)
```

The error this prints is referring to the line `done << (echo "$hasUsrLocal")`

```
./deploy.sh: line 563: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./deploy.sh: line 563: `        done << (echo "$hasUsrLocal")'
```

I'll get a similar issue for `done << (find MyProgram.app -type f -print0)` too if I comment out some of the script.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the author intended to use a process substitution:

```
done < <( find ...
```

You could also try piping the find into the while loop:

```
find MyProgram ... | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do ... done
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with Googling for a fix!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!  Thanks to William Pursell for the keyword "process substitution."  That gave me ground to "Google."

I noticed it was a spacing issue.  Needs to be spaced like `done < <(echo "$hasUsrLocal")` for example!

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

The `<<` symbol is for here-documents. What you probably want is redirected process substitution:

```
< <( : )
```

The `<(command_list)` construct is for [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution), while the first less-than symbol redirects standard input of your loop to the file descriptor created by the process substitution that follows it on the line.

#### Pro Tip

This is a handy but confusing syntax. It really helps to read it from right to left.